# xcode 10.1: Timer stops at 1 not 0

Tags: swift, timer, counter

Yep, I have seen a few questions similar to mine but for some reason, I couldn't duplicate it! If I use == or <= with If both are giving me stop at 1. The only < gave me the 0 stops which are good, but very rare I got -1. Any help, please?

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

    var timer = Timer()
    var timeLeft = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timeLabel.text = String(10)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func pressTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        startButton.isEnabled = false
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(startTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func startTime() {
        timeLeft -= 1
        timeLabel.text = "\(timeLeft)"

        if timeLeft < 0 {
            startButton.isEnabled = false
            self.timer.invalidate() 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to declare the timer as optional and check for zero **before** decrementing the counter.

And set the counter to 10 in the `pressTimer` method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

    var timer : Timer?

    var timeLeft = 0

    @IBAction func pressTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        startButton.isEnabled = false
        timeLeft = 10
        timeLabel.text = String(timeLeft)
        if timer == nil {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(startTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func startTime()
    {
        if timeLeft == 0 {
            startButton.isEnabled = false // shouldn't it be true??
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        } else {
            timeLeft -= 1
            timeLabel.text = String(timeLeft)
        }
    }
}
```